# Do I need to use AWS Lambda for Alexa Smart Home skills?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, alexa-skills-kit

When I select a custom skill, I can select how I will host my skill's service endpoint: either on AWS Lambda ARN (recommended) or via HTTPS.

Hosting my endpoint using AWS Lambda, a server-less compute service seems to be optional in this case.

When I select Smart Home skill, HTTPS service endpoint does not seem to be accessible anymore.

We already use GCP and my team prefers using GCP as it would make our infrastructure simpler.

Do I need to use AWS Lambda for Alexa Smart Home skills?

Comment: I had the same issues and found this, maybe could be clearest you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496045/alexa-smarthome-skill-without-aws

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, yes:

> An account with Amazon Web Services, needed for a Lambda function to host the skill code. Skills built with the Smart Home API must be hosted on AWS Lambda.

You can read more about it [in the docs: Alexa Skills Kit > Requirements to Build a Skill > What do you need for a smart home skill?](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/ask-overviews/requirements-to-build-a-skill.html#what-do-you-need-for-a-smart-home-skill)